# Jquery 1.11.2 not available using bower with visual studio 2015 RC

Tags: bower, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

I am just trying vs 2015 RC, and the intellisense for jquery in the bower.json file does not return the 1.x.xx versions, just 2.X

I need to use the latest before 2.0

http://screencast.com/t/ohYu8PVmmk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall previous 2.x version. Open `project.json` file and type correct 1.x.x version of jquery, even if VS does not auto complete. Restore packages of bower dependencies. Run bower install from Grunt or Grub.